# Auto Updating Core Files In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, include

Need some help.
I'm trying to auto update my wordpress site to the new version and it simply won't. The following code comes up:

`Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Unable to create file /home/theround/public_html/wp-content/tmp/wordpress-4.tmp because Permission denied in /home/theround/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 155`

`Warning: unlink(/home/theround/public_html/wp-content/tmp/wordpress-4.tmp) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/theround/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 457`

Has anyone any ideas? I've been googleing the question to no avail. I've tried adding various lines of code into the config file but it no avail and I'm at my wits end.
To be honest I don't even know what all that means. I have checked the files and they're there with correct permissions, etc... and checked them against other wordpress sites and they're the same...

Comment: What do you mean, *auto-updating core files*?

Answer (score 1):

The file permissions seem to be set wrong. More information can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress

Also if you are using your own server then make sure that the wordpress user has ownership of the directory.

e.g. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/WordPress/Installation` for linux.